# Use image alt attribute value as heading in carousel

Tags: jquery, html, jcarousel

Here is my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/yX5vr/3/

What I want to do is, simply set `h1` using currently active image's alt. It must be set on both situations: when you click on thumb, or when you just enter to the page it must be set to initial value (first image's alt).

Because of JS's a bit difficult form, I can't figure out where to place code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a callback on the scroll event:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yX5vr/36

```
$('.carousel-stage').on('jcarousel:scrollend', function(event, carousel) {
    $('.wrapper h1').text( $(this).jcarousel('visible').find('img').attr('alt') );
});
```

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/events.html#scrollend

---

To get the initial title, add this somewhere after your init:

```
$('.wrapper h1').text( $('.carousel-stage').jcarousel('visible')
    .find('img').attr('alt') );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yX5vr/37/

Comment: what about first time when you open page?

Comment: You'd do the same on init. You'll also have to get the index of the image. Right now it only grabs the first image's alt value.

Comment: what about initial value?

Comment: Updated to use current slide index and `this`.

Comment: Updated again to provide cake and help you eat it, too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
item.on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
    carouselNavigation.jcarousel('scrollIntoView', this);
    item.addClass('active');
    $('.wrapper h1').html($('.carousel-stage img').eq(item.index()).prop('alt'));
});
```

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yX5vr/35/)